# Multiple NSTableViews selection

Tags: macos, cocoa, nstableview

I have 2 tableviews in my App which I am using in a similar way to the following screenshot:

[image: Example of App design]

My problem is that I want to be able to select items in each list and have the selection remain blue rather than changing to grey when the control loses focus.

I've found that if I overload the AcceptsFirstResponder method of the tableview, I am able keep the grey for selection but this isn't the desired look of the App.

Does anyone have any advice on how I can achieve this? I was thinking I might be able change the grey to a blue whilst keeping the overloading AcceptsFirstResponder method but I'm not sure if this is possible.

Cheers,
Mike

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure your NSTableView is view-based, and check out NSTableRowView’s

```
- (void)drawSelectionInRect:(NSRect)dirtyRect;
```

BTW, I’m duty-bound to urge you not to do this: the colors have meanings in the UI. That blue color means “if you hit a key (like up arrow), this is the view that’ll receive it.” Your users will be confused.

Comment: I'm going to take your advice and look again at how I achieve this. I'm thinking using a NSOutlineView for the furthest left list will give me a good enough look whilst keeping the UI consistent with other Mac Apps.